# Evolution of the sense of Logos

Tags: etymology

So this term has had a lot of impact religiously and philosophically, yet I still do not understand why logos as discourse or word was taken by Stoics and Platonists as some divine principle and by scientists as logic or -logy, like biology, geology, etc. What does that have to do?

I mean you can make sense of the later sense as discourse of life, discourse of the earth, the list of things that can be said about life or earth. But why logic, what does that have to do with it? What does "word" have to do with "a divine intermediary that builds or animates the world"? Can anyone explain how the senses of the word evolve? Some references for this transition?

Comment: If you take into account that the Greeks made no distinction between language and thought, then things clear up a bit. In fact, they believed that only properly expressed language (i.e, their language, in this case, Greek of one form or another) was capable of proper thought (other languages were barbarous - "bar bar bar bar"; not Greek). The miracle which still amazes philosophers is the link between language and thought; the ancients noticed the miracle, but they just gave it a name. Which was "in the beginning", according to St. John, who also noticed the miracle.

Comment: Wow. Can you give me a source? Not for the "bar" thing but the fact they believed that it was a miracle that there was a link between thought and language, that would really solve the issue. Yet in neuroscience this is false, you can think wordlessly. But if greek philosophers thought that there was a link and said so explicitly, that would explain things

Comment: They didn't distinguish between thought and language. They thought there was no difference. But they did worry about where thought came from, and all the worry and the examples were expressed in Greek, a language. What the classic philosophers thought was a miracle was simply the existence of thought, and that's what they wrote about. And what moderns try to sort out.

Comment: But do you have a source? Thank you for the useful info. As I said I think it answers my question

Comment: Look up "language", "thought", and "Greek philosophy" on google and see what comes out. There's a LOT of research on it.